# Why .Net Core Shared Framework still on 2.0?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I can't run `.Net 2.1` projects, as `dotnet --info` returns the following:

```
Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.201
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  7932dc6179

Runtime Environment:
 ...
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.7
  Build    : 2d61d0b043915bc948ebf98836fefe9ba942be11
```

It could be that this question has already been asked before, but after a lot of searching I could not find anything. I want to update to 2.1, how do I do this?

I have tried installing `.Net SDK 2.1`, which is already installed if you check the `Base Path`, install a newer version of `dotnet`, etc. But whatever I install, it does not update the `2.0.7` to a `2.1.x` version.

My computer is running Windows 10.

**Edit:**

Here is the error I get when I run a 2.1 project;

```
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.
Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower,
or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1.
```

Comment: do you have a global.json anywhere? what makes you think you can't run 2.1 projects - i.e. what happens?

Comment: Use `dotnet --list-runtimes` and `dotnet --list-versions`. What do tehse show?

Comment: Can't you just download the latest .Net core 2 SDK https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't have a `global.json`, as far as I know. When I run a dotnet 2.1 project, I get an error which you can find in the edit of the mainpost

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Both return a `unknown uption` error after which all available commands are displayed. Both commands you gave aren't in there.

Comment: @JsonStatham I have tried that a couple of times, without success

Comment: Please create a `global.json` in the folder, and point to a .NET Core 2.1 SDK (2.1.201 is for .NET Core 2.0), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json and then run `dotnet --info` to confirm that you do get the right SDK version.